# Rails 3 - Handle Incoming Messages (Allowing Users to reply to email notifications)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Right now my app sends out email notifications. I'd like to allow the user to reply directly to the email, which then gets ingested by my app and inserted into the database.

Are there any Rails gems, services, tutorials that can point me in the right direction.

Also, probably need to make the reply-to email have a UID, replyto--UID@domain.com, so I don't have to rely on the from (sender).

What do you think?

Thanks

Comment: How did you go about doing it?

Comment: How did you end up doing this? In particular the `reply-to-UID@domain.com`. Any insights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few good articles to get you started:

http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2008/10/27/using-gmail-with-imap-to-receive-email-in-rails/

http://jasonseifer.com/2009/04/24/receving-email-with-rails

Answer (score 1):

We have a free service that posts incoming email to a url of your application (same as sendgrid API):
http://www.smtp2web.com

You can also use the mailman gem if you want to poll for the email at regular intervals:
https://github.com/titanous/mailman

As far as the 'replyto--UID@domain.com' kind of email addresses are concerned, you will have to create a catch-all address for your domain (it is better if you use a obscure subdomain, as it would reduce the amount of spam) which forwards all such email to a given mailbox(say notifications@domain.com).

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend using [CloudMailin](http://www.cloudmailin.com/) for the same.

It provides you a receiving email address, which you can add as a reply-to header in your mail.

About the unique UID, for tracking each reply in context of the sent email, you could generate a random string, and modify your reply-to header as "[email provided by cloudmailin]+[your random string]"

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to look at configuring your sendmail/postfix to accept incoming mail first off ( if you're using unix based server ).

Heres a good article:

http://jasonseifer.com/2009/04/24/receving-email-with-rails

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sendgrid to parse incoming email and have it send along to your app via a web-post.

This is a [decent tutorial (heroku focused)](http://nanceskitchen.com/2010/02/21/accept-incoming-emails-into-a-heroku-app-using-sendgrid/)

Or you can view Sendgrid's [ParseAPI](http://sendgrid.com/documentation/ApiParse) to see how to integrate.

Comment: But the catch here is that you need to pay $80(i.e. buy a plan of $80 or higher) for that. It is available only for silver plan and above users as on date.

Comment: @amit_saxena: that is definitely a new catch (since november when originally wrote this answer).